# Best model for Antimicrobial Resistance (AMR) prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, data-science-model, model-selection, bioinformatics

Some classes of problem are best solved by a specific class of machine learning model, due to the structure of the data (e.g. CNN's for computer vision tasks).

Prediction of bacterial resistance/susceptibility to antimicrobials (from genotypic data) using Machine Learning methods is a problem that has started receiving interest in recent years.

The following paper (from 2017) analysed the then current literature and found that:

> To date, **there has not been a consensus** about the optimal machine learning model to be used for AST genotype–phenotype prediction, as reflected by the diverse algorithms authors have implemented (Table 1).
>
> - [*Machine learning: novel bioinformatics approaches for combating antimicrobial resistance*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28914640)
>   Macesica, Polubriaginof, Tatonettib (2017)

**Has this changed in the past 2 years?**

**Is there now a consensus about which models are most effective?**

---

<sup>**References:**</sup> <sup>Table 1 from paper:</sup>

[image]